bind9' - Response Rate Limit
I’m running BIND9 inside a Docker container and noticing a lot of messages like this:

bind9  | 13-Nov-2024 22:39:13.792 queries: info: client @0x7f81a0077000 200.55.244.14#7459 (.): query: . IN ANY +E(0) (172.19.0.2)

I’m now attempting to implement “Response Rate Limiting (RRL)” by following BIND Best Practices - Authoritative and/or Using Response Rate Limiting (RRL). However, even after adding the following configuration, it doesn’t seem to be making any difference:
options {
         …
          rate-limit {
              responses-per-second 5;
          };
      };

my environment:
$ docker --version
Docker version 27.3.1, build ce12230
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.29.7
$ cat /etc/debian_version
12.7
$ uname -a
Linux X 6.1.0-26-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.112-1 (2024-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ docker images internetsystemsconsortium/bind9
REPOSITORY                        TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
internetsystemsconsortium/bind9   9.21      2fe7f58e77a3   4 weeks ago   371MB
$

Please advise)
Thank you in advance!

not sure why it didn't work the first time around, but i got it to work..
bind9  | 14-Nov-2024 01:44:08.989 rate-limit: info: client @0x7f9c7e936000 200.55.244.14#29723 (.): rate limit slip response to 200.55.244.0/24 for . IN ANY  (ea9c9824)
bind9  | 14-Nov-2024 01:44:09.277 queries: info: client @0x7f9c99923000 200.55.244.14#2757 (.): query: . IN ANY +E(0) (172.19.0.2)

